# No thermal throttling in Raspberry Pi 3 model B?

Tags: temperature, measuring

I am seeing that the thermal throttling doesn't work while you read the frequency from:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

And thermal information from:

```
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp
```

[Here's](https://github.com/Souravgoswami/ruby-masterclass/blob/master/Section%2040:%20introduction%20to%20Benchmarking/SystemMonitorPi.rb) simple Ruby script I wrote:
[image]

The problem you see, the temperature goes to 71℃ and it's still overclocked. In fact, the frequencies don't reduce even when the pi is running at 80℃.

What's the problem with my pi?

Answer (score 1):

Did you change kernel or did avoid_warnings flag in /boot/config.txt (it only disables power warning normally).

If you have compiled a vanilla branch from kernel.org with cherry picked commits from raspbean kernel, it may be missing thermal throttle code.

Which governor are you running.

Comment: I am just using the Arch-Linux ARM's Kernel, and I don't even have the `avoid_warnings` flag in the /boot/config.txt...

Comment: It's weird. The ambient temperature here is 40℃. The temperature of the pi goes to 85℃ easily if you are just using the browser, and no thermal throttling can lead to severe damages!